# How to sort Wk no-Year(02-2018, 03-2019, 04-2018..) using macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, sorting

I want to sort the week number and year in pivot table.

I tried to sort with pivot table and it is not properly sorting.

Can anyone help how to sort with the help of macro or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Without a macro:  insert two new columns that contain respectively, the week number and year information.  Assuming your date info (02-2018) is in cell A2, in cell B2 you would use:

```
=left(A2, 2)
```

to get the week number and in cell C2 you could use:

```
=right(A2, 4)
```

to get the year info.

Then sort your data based on the year at first level and the week number at second level.

Next, hide the two additional columns.